# Deploying JHipster app on eu-west-2

Tags: amazon-web-services, jhipster

When deploying a JHipster app, I ran

```
jhipster aws
```

I received a list of locations to deploy. Unfortunately, `eu-west-2` (London) wasn't in the list. Is it not supported? Could that be resolved somehow?

Comment: Sure - [add it](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)

Comment: Yes you should add it, please open an issue on github and submit a pull request https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/aws/prompts.js#L99-L100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Jan 19th, 2018, JHipster doesn't support `eu-west-2` in its [generator](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/aws/prompts.js#L99-L100). A pull request was sent and hopefully will be merged in the upcoming milestone. Updates on the pull request can be found [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/7013).